# Incrementing Timestamps

Tags: python, xml, datetime, time

I have a Python script converting multiple csv lists into one xml document with time stamps for each row
I already have the format set as:

```
TS = datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')+ "Z"
```

calling TS will give me this time stamp = `2020-02-14T14:30:59.237Z`

I need to reuse this variable possibly 100k times or more in my XML document and this creates the exact same time, every time I call the variable. How can I increment the time stamp by 1 millisecond every time it is called in the script??

Comment: since your are assigning a value to TS, it wont change, unless you change it.

Comment: "calling TS", "I call the variable" - it's not possible to call a string. Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I Have several places in my xml file I need to put a timestamp but I need the first timestamp to start on the date and time that I run the python script and each timestamp after that to increment by 1 millisecond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use something like this generator?

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

def getTimestamp():
    timestamp = dt.timestamp(dt.now())
    while True:
        timestamp += 1
        yield dt.fromtimestamp((timestamp)/1000).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + "Z"

TS = getTimestamp()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(TS))
```

Comment: This did increment the time stamp in the correct format but the date and Time are not even close. I would like to know how I can get the date and time to start at the correct time. im currently getting:1970-01-19T02:22:04.766Z from this

Comment: I used :def getTimestamp():
    timestamp = dt.timestamp(dt.now())
    while True:
        timestamp += .314
        yield dt.fromtimestamp((timestamp)/1).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + "Z"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the difference between a variable and a function.
You do not "call" a variable, unless you have specifically assigned it a value *as a function*.

You did not do this.  Your given code *call*s `now` and `isoformat`, returning a *string* value.  You put this value into `TS` for safekeeping.  Referring multiple times to `TS` does *not* change its value: it refers to the "once and future" string value, *not* to any process that would update that value.

If you want to update the time stamp, [do so explicitly](/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python): add a `timedelta` of one millisecond to it on each loop iteration.